# Gmail product carousel schema query

Tags: google-schemas

We have had success in editing the product carousel schema in your preview tool, see below:

[preview on Google for carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ho1v.png)

However, when inserting this script (microdata) into Emarsys email html template and testing this, the carousel does not render.

Can you please take a look:

[text](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bPJY35Eo7ct9uQWPBihizENIlBKRs5trRrQpRAW9zPY/edit?usp=sharing)

Please flag what we're doing wrong as we're really keen to launch this next week for a big commercial campaign.

Many thanks,
Jemma Sharman Nobody's Child
jemma.sharman@nobodyschild.com